# why does this code print none after what it is supposed to?

Tags: python

why does this code print

Hello

None

None

```
def begin ():
    print("Type new to start a new game or load to load the previous game")
    print prompt_start()

def start ():
    print("hello")

def prompt_start ():
    prompt_0 = raw_input("Type  command:")
    if prompt_0==("new"):
        print start()
    elif prompt_0==("load"):
        load()
    else:
        print("read instructions!")
        print prompt_start

begin()
```

please give solutions to this as i can't figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Because each function has an implicit `return None`, your `prompt_start()` function returns `None`. `print prompt_starts()` prints what the function call returns: `None`.

[A relevant question that may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you functions `prompt_start()` and `prompt_start()` don't return anything. Thus, when you write `print prompt_start()`, Python evaluates your functions and then tries to print its results (which in your case is `None`, as it doesn't return anything).

Below is the code that doesn't print `None`:

```
def begin ():
    print("Type new to start a new game or load to load the previous game")
    prompt_start()

def start ():
    print("hello")

def prompt_start ():
    prompt_0 = raw_input("Type  command:")
    if prompt_0==("new"):
        print start()
    elif prompt_0==("load"):
        load()
    else:
        print("read instructions!")
        prompt_start() # <- missing parens  to call the function
begin()
```